# KQL script - How to compute total seconds per Success (True/False)

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer

Given the Timegenerated and Success fields
In Kusto script

1. How to get the total seconds of each row for True and false
2. Get the total seconds for the true and false (for this sample how to get 33 for true and 7 for false

[image]

I used the

| serialize
| extend Timediff = (prev(TimeGenerated, 1) - TimeGenerated)/1sec

but im having a challenge to get the false/true

Im just getting the diff of each record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
| serialize
| extend TimeDiff = (next(TimeGenerated, 1) - TimeGenerated)/1s
| summarize TotalSeconds = sum(TimeDiff) by Success
```

You can use summarize operator and group the data based on the value of success field and sum the `Timediff` values. This will give the total seconds for true and false separately.

**Output:**

| Success | TotalSeconds |
| --- | --- |
| true | 33 |
| false | 7 |

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42SQQqDMBBF94J3mGUCliaxUhC6K/QAuitdRDOCEBVMhLb08B1tXbhpk4RAfh5/hvwY7WlWFlkx1TU6l1fDYBMo2w4v2OOoPZrc0O5J4XF0jSOg4ccJE1h1poRSOyFpgVS5kLnIePIhG23dT1SKFf1nKrNQUoWXT4PLpyqYDG40PQY3esjo+W9x9AKHY6tt+0SYT3j32JslsXPbNHAC1pPGNhEmIDnstrHyvXSL3dR1epztysFrW2A99MaRD12w1ZZD9YDvH3kDsgBpWDUCAAA=)

**Update**

```
| serialize 
| extend TimeDiff = (next(TimeGenerated, 1) - TimeGenerated)/1s
| extend true_per_sec = iif(Success=='true',TimeDiff,real(null)), false_per_sec = iif(Success=='false',TimeDiff,real(null))
| summarize  TimeDiff=sum(TimeDiff), true_per_sec=sum(true_per_sec), false_per_sec=sum(false_per_s
```

Comment: Thanks @Aswin

Can I ask some additional steps that I need to compute

Var
Sec/day =60
True= 33

Comment: What is Sec/day?

Comment: Thanks @Aswin

Can I ask some additional steps that I need to compute

hardcoded Secday =60

sumTrueFalse = 33+ 7=40

Gap= Secday - sumTrueFalse  =20


AVG= ( TRUE 33 + Gap 20) / secday 60 = 0.88

Comment: This is confusing, Can you share the expectation in table format

Comment: or is it possible to have the results in one row? 

Columns are True |  False | TotaL |

then values will be
33    |   7      |  40  |

Comment: Edited the answer..

Comment: Many thanks Aswin for the help